# Write data into csv file in single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i am able to fetch the data and print it using API URL and below is my code

```
import re
import json
import warnings
import urllib.request
import csv

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')

url = "http://machineXYZ.local:4450/api/35/project/ProjectName01/executions"
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token': '#Tokens here#'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify = False)
#print(response.text.encode('utf8'))

response_value = response.json()
response_value = json.dumps(response_value)
resp = json.loads(response_value)
with open('execute.csv','w') as executeData:
i = resp['executions']

with open('ExecOutput.csv','w') as executeData:
    for a in i:

        try:
            if (a['id']==0):
                print("Is empty")
            else:
                print("Job ID is : " + str(a['id']))
                csvWriter = csv.writer(executeData,delimiter=',')
                csvWriter.writerow(str(a['id']))
                for a in
        except KeyError:
            print("Job ID: Key error issue, Check input again")

        try:
            if(a['project']==0):
                print("Project data not available")
            else:
                print("Project Name: "+a['project'])
                csvWriter = csv.writer(executeData, delimiter=',')
                csvWriter.writerow(a['project'])
        except KeyError:
            print("Project Name: Key error issue, Check input again")

        try:
            if(a['name']==null):
                print("Job Name not available")
            else:
                print("JobName: "+a['name'])
                csvWriter = csv.writer(executeData)
                csvWriter.writerow(str(a['name']))
        except KeyError:
            print("JobName: key Error check again")
print("\n")
```

And the output is

```
    {
      "id": 2,
      "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/execution/2",
      "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/2",
      "status": "succeeded",
      "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
      "executionType": "scheduled",
      "user": "admin",
      "date-started": {
        "unixtime": 1608296400032,
        "date": "2020-12-18T13:00:00Z"
      },
      "date-ended": {
        "unixtime": 1608296400374,
        "date": "2020-12-18T13:00:00Z"
      },
      "job": {
        "id": "f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9",
        "averageDuration": 590,
        "name": "HelloWorld",
        "group": "",
        "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
        "description": "",
        "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/job/f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9",
        "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/f2a837d2-1a9c-4387-89d7-0243bbfe6ba9"
      },
      "description": "echo \"hi\"",
      "argstring": null,
      "serverUUID": "94ac86b1-56e9-4bc3-9a4c-50cd7c8a5b59",
      "successfulNodes": [
        "localhost"
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

i am capturing output as below

```
Job ID is : 691
```

Project Name: Project - D
JobName: key Issue
Status: succeeded
User Description: admin

Job ID is : 690
Project Name: Project - Y
JobName: Server Check
Status: succeeded
User Description: John

Job ID is : 689
Project Name: Project - D
JobName: key Error check again
Status: succeeded
User Description: admin

so when i am writing it in Csv file, the output in am getting is
[image: OUTPUT I HAVE GOT]

Desired Output format is:
[image]

Can you please help where i need to make change and what

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the response JSON object

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, logs should be provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @NasserTahani Updated the response JSON object, can you check

Comment: Open the generated CSV file as *text* file, rather than let Excel try and interpret it (possibly wrong). Is it correctly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to use the ***csv*** module according to your coding approach. Use the snippet below to write each line. Also, you can create a simple function for all response elements to simplify your code.

```
res_list = []
with open('ExecOutput.csv','w') as writer:
    for a in i:

        try:
            if (a['id']==0):
                print("Is empty")
                res_list.append('')
            else:
                print("Job ID is : " + str(a['id'])) 
                res_list.append(str(a['id']))
               
        except KeyError:
            print("Job ID: Key error issue, Check input again")

        try:
            if(a['project']==0):
                print("Project data not available")
                res_list.append('')
            else:
                print("Project Name: "+a['project'])
                res_list.append(str(a['project']))
                
        except KeyError:
            print("Project Name: Key error issue, Check input again")

        try:
            if(a['name']):
                print("Job Name not available")
                res_list.append('')
            else:
                print("JobName: "+a['name'])
                res_list.append(str(str(a['name'])))
        except KeyError:
            print("JobName: key Error check again")
        
        writer.write(','.join(res_list) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in the csv its all coming in one single line, even though have used same code as u mentioned.